# How to use django.contrib.humanize filter in DRF serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

is it possible to use the Django `humanize` filter for drf on the serializers

i have tried putting `naturaltime` in the to_representation method like below

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super(ListUsersSerializer,
                           self).to_representation(instance)
    representation['last_login'] = instance.last_login(naturaltime)
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the data through the `naturaltime` filter, with:

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime

def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super().to_representation(instance)
    representation['last_login'] = naturaltime(instance.last_login)
    return representation
```

Note that Django's `naturaltime` uses a [*non-breaking space* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) between a number and its unit, not a normal space, so:

```
>>> naturaltime(datetime(2019, 11, 25))
'2\xa0years, 2\xa0months ago'
```